# would a typical spring boot web-app be packaged and launched as WAR or JAR?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a fairly basic CRUD webapp developed in spring-boot with Spring-STS IDE, and now i intend to deploy it to a webserver.

I'm asking in order to understand the best practices

thanks

Comment: WAR means Web-ARchive, so war is right in your case

Comment: Spring Boot recommends using a jar (which is also simpler).

Comment: and if i have several apps, then deploy several JARs ?  this seems counter intuitive, because each of them would have the webserver included, which bloats the JAR

Comment: A few MBs of disk space should be the least of your concerns.

Comment: @JBNizet you'd be stopping the webservice when you want to replace/update the jar file. 
wouldn't war deployment to a container like tomcat be faster ?

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy a Spring Boot app to a JEE app server such as Glassfish, Jboss, Websphere or whatever, you can run into a world of pain as the aforementioned app servers tend to ship with their own versions of certain apis, which will override any jars that ship with Spring Boot.

So personally I'd avoid a JEE app server if you can. Either deploy to Tomcat, or better still just ship a JAR containing an embedded servlet engine of your choice (e.g. Tomcat, Undertow).

This stops you getting into trying to resolve jar conflicts, and also means you never have to worry about upgrading or even installing app servers.